# Why can't I log in using requests Python?

Tags: python, http, python-requests

I can't log in to parse user data. The form tag looks like:

```
<form name="form_auth" class="authorization-form" method="post" target="_top" action="/personal/?login=yes">
```

Python code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def auth(login, password):

    url = "https://fix-price.ru/personal/"
    param = {'login': login, 'password': password}
    r = requests.post(url, data=param)
    page = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'lxml')

    return page


page = auth('some_mail@gmail.com', 'some_password')

about_user = page.find('div', class_='header-right')
```

why it doesn't work?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: The url endpoint: `action="/personal/?login=yes"`, You have to pass **ALL** `<form .../> <input ... />` fields, which you didn't show,  in `data`

Comment: That depends on the website's security system. It may check the URL (your URL is missing the "get" part: "?login=yes"), it may check the request headers for HTTP_REFERER or some cookies set by the authorization form page.

Comment: I tried everything, turned it on ?login=yes too, passed all fields. Does not work

Answer (score 0):

And so, I solved the problem as follows. The address in the "action" attribute does not always refer to the handler script. It is necessary to look in the browser, on what script there is a request after pressing submit. In my case, the address was " `/ajax/auth_user.php`. You also need to look at what parameters are passed in addition to yours.

The working code is:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def auth(login, password):
    url = "https://fix-price.ru/ajax/auth_user.php"
    param = {
        'AUTH_FORM':'Y',
        'TYPE':'AUTH',
        'backurl':'/personal/',
        'login': login,
        'password': password
    }
    r = requests.post(url, data=param)
    page = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'lxml')

    return page


page = auth('some_mail@gmail.com', 'some_password')

about_user = page.find('div', class_='header-right')
```